# How to memoize a class method with META PROGRAMMING?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

EDIT: To be clear.  This is a question about how to do something with meta programming.  It's not about memoizing.  Clearly there are better ways to memoize.  The relevant methods have "memoize" in them just to illustrate their purpose.

---

I'm just toying around with meta programming, so please don't answer use a
`@foo` instance variable.

I have the following that tries to memoize both an instance and a class method
by overwriting the method definition from the running method..

```
class Obj
  class << self

    def meta_me; self; end

    def class_memoize
      puts "hard core calculating ..."
      abc = "huge calculation result"

      raise "broken here with infinite loop"

      define_class_method "class_memoize" do
        puts abc
        abc
      end
      class_memoize
    end

    def define_class_method name, &blk
      meta_me.instance_eval do
        define_method name, &blk
      end
    end
  end

  def instance_memoize
    puts "hard core calculating ..."
    abc = "huge calculation result"

    self.class.meta_me.send :define_method, :instance_memoize do
      puts abc
      abc
    end

    instance_memoize
  end
end

o = Obj.new
o.instance_memoize
# hard core calculating ...
# huge calculation result

o.instance_memoize
# huge calculation result
```

The instance version works, but the class version does not.

I've left in an attempt at the class version for reference.

Comment: What you're doing here seems like an astoundingly bad idea. How do you un-memoize something? You can't reset it without going back to the old method which you've stomped and no longer exists.

Comment: Did you miss the part where this is a metaprogramming exercise?

Comment: @tadman assuming you were the one who voted to close and did downvote.  WHY??? That is _ridiculous_.  I'm interested in learning meta programming, how is this "not a question"?

Comment: Well, you know what happens when you assume. It wasn't me. I still think what you're doing here is the worst kind of sorcery, though. You can call it "metaprogramming" if you want, but I'd call it an express bus to unmaintainable code. Maybe you should be asking a question about the core feature required: Dynamically defining and re-defining a class method.

Comment: yeah, that's not the best example, but dynamically redefining methods is not uncommon in Ruby. It's fairly metaprogramming-positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethics aside, It's much easier than you think. Your main issue is you're using the wrong thing for your meta_me method. Try this:

```
class Object
  def metaclass
    class<<self;self;end
  end
end
```

This is a fairly common monkeypatch when doing metaprogramming in Ruby. Now it's easy to reimplement a method, dynamically:

```
class Obj
  def self.class_memoize
    puts "calculating..."
    abc = "result"
    metaclass.send(:define_method, :class_memoize) do
      puts abc
      abc
    end
    class_memoize
  end

  def instance_memoize
    puts "calculating..."
    abc = "result"
    metaclass.send(:define_method, :instance_memoize) do
      puts abc
      abc
    end
    instance_memoize
  end
end
```

As you can see, once you have the metaclass object, redefining the methods done the same way whether it's a class method or an instance method. Note that if you don't want to sully the whole namespace with a metaclass method, it's probably better just to use the `class<<self;self;end` idiom whenever you want to refer to it. You can call methods directly on it, like this:

```
(class<<self;self;end).send(:define_method, :foo){|bar| bar*23}
```

Note that the parens aren't truly needed, it just helps to contain the messiness that is the bare metaclass reference :) Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This was helpful.  I'm confused about the effect of my code though.  Where did `class_memoize` end up?  I couldn't call it from anything.

Comment: These things can be tricky, but I *think* that since `meta_me` was `self` of the class, when you called `define_method` on it, the method was defined as an ordinary instance method. Try calling `Obj.class_memoize`, then `Obj.new.class_memoize`, I think that you will find the method is defined.